Understanding company-mode, corfu, and lsp-mode
I'm trying to switch to Emacs for all my text-related tasks. I've set up org-mode for note-taking, but configuring it as a programming tool is overwhelming. I am aware of many questions here that ask how to configure Emacs as a complete "IDE" (Emacs as a C/C++ IDE Emacs for large Go projects Python IDE with Emacs), but most mention outdated packages. I believe I narrowed it down to three main active packages: company-mode, corfu, and lsp-mode. Can someone explain how these interact with each other?
Specifically, I'd like to know:

Why choose between company-mode (older) and corfu (newer), which both provide similar functionality?
How does lsp-mode come into play?
Do these packages provide access to documentation and code navigation in Emacs?
Is it possible to replicate features like "Go to definition/declaration/references" and file outline from other IDEs?

How would I configure these packages for Python development, with C/C++ and Rust as potential future targets?

That's a very wide topic, appropriate for a blog but not for Emacs SE. I'd suggest you ask on r/emacs (the Reddit channel for Emacs) and/or search the web for blogs/tutorials on these topics.

See also this newer page, uses company and lsp-mode.
